# Orchard 1.10.2 TryUpdateModel not working after upgrade from 1.7

Tags: orchardcms

Newbie to Orchard CMS

After upgrading an existing Orchard site running version 1.7 to version 1.10.2, some (not all) of my content part drivers are no longer updating the part properties with the new values entered into the form on add or edit.

When I go into add or edit an item, the only property that is saved is an MediaPickerField that is a field of the part.

I have compared the non-working code with working content part drivers in the solution and I can't see anything that is different from them that would cause the issue.

TryUpdateModel is returning true, but none of the values on the form flow through. On Add, there will be a record in the DB with all empty fields except the Id. The driver returns the edit view with a message that the part was added successfully, but all the fields are cleared out except the Image field.

Here is the code for one of the parts having the issue.

```
public class FeaturedPromoPartRecord : ContentPartRecord {
    [StringLength(100)]
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }

    [StringLengthMax]
    public virtual string LinkUrl { get; set; }

    public virtual FeaturedPromoGroupPartRecord FeaturedPromoGroupPartRecord { get; set; }

    public virtual int SlideOrder { get; set; }

    public virtual DateTime? StartDate { get; set; }

    public virtual DateTime? EndDate { get; set; }
}

public class FeaturedPromoPart : ContentPart<FeaturedPromoPartRecord> {
    public string Name
    {
        get { return Record.Name; }
        set { Record.Name = value; }
    }

    public string LinkUrl {
        get { return Record.LinkUrl; }
        set { Record.LinkUrl = value; }
    }

    public FeaturedPromoGroupPartRecord FeaturedPromoGroupPartRecord
    {
        get { return Record.FeaturedPromoGroupPartRecord; }
        set { Record.FeaturedPromoGroupPartRecord = value; }
    }

    public int SlideOrder {
        get { return Record.SlideOrder; }
        set { Record.SlideOrder = value; }
    }

    public DateTime? StartDate
    {
        get { return Record.StartDate; }
        set { Record.StartDate = value; }
    }

    public DateTime? EndDate
    {
        get { return Record.EndDate; }
        set { Record.EndDate = value; }
    }
}

public class FeaturedPromoPartDriver : ContentPartDriver<FeaturedPromoPart> {
    private readonly IFeaturedPromoService _featuredPromoService;

    public FeaturedPromoPartDriver(IFeaturedPromoService featuredPromoService) {
        _featuredPromoService = featuredPromoService;
        T = NullLocalizer.Instance;
    }

    public Localizer T { get; set; }

    protected override DriverResult Display(FeaturedPromoPart part, string displayType, dynamic shapeHelper) {
        var group = _featuredPromoService.GetFeaturedPromoGroup(part.FeaturedPromoGroupPartRecord.Id);

        return ContentShape("Parts_FeaturedPromo_SummaryAdmin",
            () => shapeHelper.Parts_FeaturedPromo_SummaryAdmin(ContentPart: part, ContentItem: part.ContentItem, Group: group));
    }

    protected override DriverResult Editor(FeaturedPromoPart part, dynamic shapeHelper) {
        var groups = _featuredPromoService.GetFeaturedPromoGroups();

        var viewModel = new FeaturedPromoEditViewModel
        {
            Groups = groups,
            Name = part.Name,
            FeaturedPromoGroupPartRecordId = (part.FeaturedPromoGroupPartRecord == null) ? 0 : part.FeaturedPromoGroupPartRecord.Id,
            LinkUrl = part.LinkUrl,
            SlideOrder = part.SlideOrder,
            StartDate = part.StartDate,
            EndDate = part.EndDate
        };
        return ContentShape("Parts_FeaturedPromo_Edit",
            () => shapeHelper.EditorTemplate(TemplateName: "Parts.FeaturedPromo.Edit", Model: viewModel));
    }

    protected override DriverResult Editor(FeaturedPromoPart part, IUpdateModel updater, dynamic shapeHelper) {

        var result = updater.TryUpdateModel(part, Prefix, null, null);

        var group = _featuredPromoService.GetFeaturedPromoGroup(part.FeaturedPromoGroupPartRecord.Id);
        if(group != null)
            part.FeaturedPromoGroupPartRecord = group._record.Value;

        if (part.StartDate.HasValue && part.EndDate.HasValue && part.StartDate > part.EndDate)
            updater.AddModelError("", T("The End Date cannot be after the Start Date."));

        return Editor(part, shapeHelper);
    }
}
```

Some images of what I'm seeing.

Edit

[image]

Add New

[image]

If anyone has encountered this issue, or has some insight on how to fix I would greatly appreciate your help!

Thank you

Comment: Looks to me that you're using a viewmodel when building the editor, while you're using the part when updating it in the POST. I didn't think that would work. As per my understanding, you need to update the viewmodel, then map the viewmodel properties manually to your part.

Comment: Show us the editor template `Parts.FeaturedPromo.Edit`. I think it's the usual input field prefix issue.